# How do I get the base URL for saving a record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to add a method that POSTs to a non-REST action such as "upload_complete":

```
POST /api/v2/cats/1/upload_complete
```

My code is similar to this, except I don't want to hardcode the URL:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  uploadComplete: function() {
    ajax('/api/v2/cats/1/upload_complete', {
      type: 'POST'
    });
  }
}
```

When I save the model, it PUTs to '/api/v2/cats/1', so it must know how to build the URL. Is there a property on the model where I can get the first part of the URL from so I only have to append "upload_complete"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `RESTAdapter`

```
this.store.adapterFor('cat').buildURL('cat', record.get('id'), record)
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L526